# Filtrar registros de mongodb por meses

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vue.js, mongodb, mongoose

Como puedo realizar una consulta por mongoose para filtrar todos los registros que esten en ese mes.

Este es mi modelo

```
import mongoose, {Schema} from 'mongoose';

const bitacoraEmbarcacionSchema = new Schema({
    agencia: {type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'agencia', required:true},
    embarcacion: {type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'embarcacion', required:true},
    atraque: {type:Date, required:true},
    desatraque: {type:Date, required:true},
    estadia: {type:Number, required:true},
    embarquePx: {type:Number, required:true},
    desembarquePx: {type:Number, required:true},
    folioServicio : {type:String,required:true},
    entrada: {type:Number,required:true},
    salida: {type:Number,required:true}

})

const bitacoraEmbarcacion = mongoose.model('bitacoraEmbarcacion',bitacoraEmbarcacionSchema);
export default bitacoraEmbarcacion
```

Este es mi Controlador

```
list: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const reg = await models.BitacoraEmbarcaciones.find({'desatraque':req.query.desatraque})
        .populate("agencia")
        .populate("embarcacion")
        .sort({ createdAt: -1 });
      res.status(200).json(reg);
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: "Ocurrio un error",
      });
      next(e);
    }
  },
```

Quiero realizar una consulta que me muestre por ejemplo todos los registros del mes de enero del 2020, usando como filtro el campo desatraque

Comment: Usar req.query.desatraque directamente en la query de mongoose es un error seguridad, ese campo debería ser validado primero para hacer match con una fecha...

Answer (score 0):

```
collection.find({}, { "sort" : [['datefield', 'asc']] });
```

La razón es que mongoose porvee una lista de opciones para la query, los cuales puedes especificar a la hora buscar, o incluso dentro de populate.

```
populate({
   ...
   options: { sort: { 'createdAt': -1 } }
})
```

Un datos más, tal como en el comentario, no uses directamente el req.query, porque es un dato sensible a la modificación del usuario. Tal como req.body, toda la información que entra debe validarse.

Por defecto esto se puede igualar: `res.status(200).json(reg);` = `res.send(reg);`

*req.status empieza por 200, no hay razón para especificar el resultado.*